# Indexing arrays with variable depths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

Is there a way how to index an array with variable depth?

e.g.

I have somewhere saved:

```
$path_string="Shop,Items,Item";
```

I will convert it to array:

```
$path = explode (",", $path_string);
```

And the number of items in the array affects the array dimension. So then, I want to index my multidimensional array like this:

```
$value = $array[$path[0]][$path[1]][$path[2]][$id][$tag];
```

I really cannot figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cursor = $array;
foreach (explode(",", $path_string) as $key) {
    $cursor = $cursor[$key];
}
var_dump($cursor);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a recursive function to do this:

```
function my_array_conversion($array) {

$ret = array();

  var_dump($array);

   if(count($array) > 1) {
      $c = $array[0];
      array_splice($array, 0, 1);
      $ret[$c] = my_array_conversion($array);
   }
   else 
      $ret[$array[0]] = array();

   return $ret;
}
```

Call it with $array = array($path[0], $path[1], $path[2], $id, $tag);